# Excel 2010 - autofill an incrementing column when data exists in some other column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, auto-form-fill

I've built a spreadsheet into which I will enter line-items.  I would like one column to auto-populate with a unique id when an entry is made.  I would also like to manage the format of the unique id.

All thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In addition you should [edit] your question to add some sample data, showing the data you have and what you expect to see when an entry is added.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

1. Format your data as a table (Insert ribbon > Table) and input a formula that creates the unique ID. If the entire column is the same formula - which it should be for this use - then Excel will automatically fill it in when you add new rows at the bottom. Be careful, though. If you generate the unique ID based on the row number, then sorting the data will mess up your unique ID.
   [image: Insert Table]
2. Use a macro. Take a look at the [Worksheet.Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event as a means to capture when the sheet is changed. It uses a `Target` parameter that is the range that was changed. You can use something like `Cells(Target.Row,1).Value` or `Range("A" & Target.Row).Value` to find the text in column A of the row that was changed. If there's no unique ID there, then add one.

As mentioned in the comments, we are not a script writing service. Take a stab at one of these options and, if things aren't working correctly, look for answers on your own. If you can't find them, come back and post a new question with as much detail as possible so we can be as helpful as possible.